# the_excerpt() in content.php and get_template_part() in single.php

Tags: content, the-content, single, excerpt, template-hierarchy

everybody. So I'm creating a blog theme and have put `the_excerpt()` in **content.php**

My **index.php** displays different post excerpts for the different kind of posts-formats. I have **content-gallery.php**, **content-audio.php**, etc and in each of them I have `the_excerpt()` instead of `the_content()`. If I put `the_content()` and there is a lot of text before the *read-more* tag, it breaks the layout, because the design is made for little snippets for each post.

Does that mean that I can't use `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() )` in **single.php**, because it will return an excerpt and not the whole content?

In the **content.php**, I could put:

```
if( is_singular() ) {
    the_content();
}
```

Or create subpages of **single.php** like **single-gallery.php**.

What is the correct way of arranging the hierarchy when using `the_excerpt()` in **content-{post-type}.php**?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing your actual code, and knowing the exact context in which it is used.

Comment: @chip-bennett Yeah, you are right. I have added more information to the post. I don't know if it is enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`the_content()` does not grab the PHP file `content.php`, it simply displays a Post's content. Likewise, `the_excerpt()` grabs the excerpt of a post.

`get_template_part` simply finds a file within your theme named whatever you put in, with an optional suffix.

```
get_template_part( 'content' ); // content.php
get_template_part( 'content', 'my_page' ); // content-my_page.php
```

in order for make different displays for Gallery, Aside, etc. do this in single.php

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

It will point to `content-gallery.php`, `content-aside.php`, etc. with a fallback of `content.php` if the file specified is not defined.

**Edit:**
All you need to do here is restructure your `content-{post-format}.php` files. Inside those, use `the_content()`, and create `excerpt-{post-format}.php` files where you can then use `the_excerpt()`.

Then your call in `index.php` would be `get_template_part( 'excerpt', get_post_format() )`, where inside your `single.php` it would be `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() )`